# Django : Primary Key is getting null value

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, sqlite

Consider the following model :

```
from django.db import models


class Album(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,null=False)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album_logo = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

    def __str__(self):
        return "id = " + str(self.id) + " artist = " + self.artist + " album = " + self.album_title + " genre = " + self.genre 

class Song(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    song_title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

    def __str__(self):
        return "id = " + str(self.id) + "album = " + self.album.album_title + "song = " + self.song_title
```

> When i am inserting a row in either Album or Song using positional parameters and not giving, django is providing **NULL** to that particular row. Why so?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, there is no need of explicitly declaring a field named 'id' as Django already creates an id field with every model by default and auto-increments it.

In any case, if you want to deliberately declare a primary key it is recommended do it in the following manner:

`id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)`

This is an auto-incrementing primary key.

Reference Official Django Docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields

Comment: Initially i didnt give any id column. but it wasnt working that time also. that's why i did like this.

Comment: You can access the default primary key of a model in filter like this:
Album.objects.get(pk=1)

Hope this clarifies :)